# Add recording duration with pyaudio in Python

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am writing a program in Python, to create and record audio file by using pyaudio. Audio file creation is done successfully but in recording, i am facing trouble because it is capturing nothing.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import sys
from datetime import datetime

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'Audio.wav'

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


frames = []
print('* done recording')

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

How can I add duration in audio recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, which I am sharing here

```
import pyaudio, wave, sys

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 10

WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'Audio_.wav'
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels = CHANNELS,
                rate = RATE,
                input = True,
                input_device_index = 0,
                frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you had to call stream.read to start the capture,seems you figured it out haha

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30248456)